# Obtain data from COM port (rs485/rs232), and broadcast the information through raspberry pi

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi2

I am working in a factory. There is a **HMI (Human Machine Interface)** tablet which control all the switches and logics of a manucfacturing machine.

For example, I can limit the speed of manufacturing or change the number of production plan easily, through the HMI.

Here is the images of the back panel of the tablet (KINSTON tablet, not KINGSTON tablet). Consist of **usb port**, **com port**, **rs-232 port**, **rs-485 port**.

What I am trying to do is to obtain the data of the manufacturing machine, and show the real-time production details to the back office of the factory. (At the mean time, I have totally no idea what the operating system the tablet is using). Or maybe using a website to control it. Or even using mobile app to monitor the condition of the machine.

***Is there any easy way to obtain data from these port to a raspberry pi and make a real time reflection of the data. To be more specific, which port should I use to obtain the data?***

How should I kickstart this project? I am total newbie of COM port, I have googled around but can't find a concrete example of connection to a computer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's going to be difficult, it is a no-name brand with no web presence.  They almost certainly did not do the engineering, just supplied the cheap hardware.  The only shot you have is contacting whatever company that took care of the system integration.  Ask around where you work, somebody that was around when the system was started up should know.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is a very useful information indeed, I have contacted the manufacturer of this manufacturing machine (NOT the manufacturer of the tablet), their answer is, the IoT of machines are under construction now, and after successful construction, they will sell me the system (Instead of teaching me how to retrieve data from the tablet) . So I guess my options are limited, either hack the tablet or pay them money. Thank you for helping me out.